# How to make shinyAce app container background transparent

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown

I created a shiny presentation using rmarkdown in which one of the slides includes a shinyAce editor (code below).  The entire app seems to be inside a container which has a white background.  I want to make the background of this container transparent using css, but has thus far I've been unable to find the right object name to apply the change to.

I've tried a simple `par(bg = NA)` and tooled around in the default css files in the `rmarkdown`, `shiny`, and `shinyAce` packages...but cant find the appropriate place to make the change.

Finally, I've included code in `mainPanel` to change the color of the background. However, this just seems to be an overlay on the white container because when I set `body {background-color: transparent`} the background remains white.

As always, any help is appreciated

````
---
title                  : "White Backgrounds are Ugly"
subtitle               : "Help me make it go away"
author                 : "Me"
date                   : "Now"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen         : true
runtime: shiny
---   

## Basic R Plot with shinyAce

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shinyAce)
shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
        aceEditor("code", mode="r", 
                  value="plot(1:5, 1:5,\nxlab = 'This is side 1',\nylab = 'This is side 2',\nmain = 'This is side 3',\nsub = 'Subtitle or Caption',\naxes = TRUE,\ntype = 'p',\nlas = 0)"),
          actionButton("eval", "Evaluate")),

      mainPanel(list(tags$head(tags$style("body {background-color: rgba(255,130,255,1); }"))), plotOutput("output"))))),

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$output <- renderPlot({
  par(bg = NA)
  input$eval
  return(isolate(eval(parse(text=input$code))))
})  
})
)
```
````